# Acess User information from a form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model which includes user object, and an extended form based on this model.
How do I access the User object's fields in the form? If this is not the way to do it, what is a recommended way?

**models.py**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DriverRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
```

**page.html** (What I would have liked to do...)

```
<label for="id_username">Username<span class="small">Add your name</span></label>{{form.user.username}}<!-- Not like this... -->
<label for="id_password">Password <span class="small">Small and big letters</span></label>{{form.user.password}}<!-- Not like this... -->
<label for="id_phone">Phone <span class="small">Your phone number</span></label>{{form.phone}}
```

Comment: You cannot acces them like that because User is another class, and therefor are not part of the Driver ModelForm. Only thing you can do in this Form is select existing users. You need to create a) another form for User creation, b) add username and password fields to DriverRegistrationForm and somehow manage to create a User in the cleaning process or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can also extend the default user creation form

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class DriverRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "phone", "password1", "password2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user details are stored in the `User` class in django's default `django.contrib.auth.models`.  This means that the values of "username" and "password" that you want the user to enter are stored separately in that `User` table in the database but is related to your custom `Driver` class.

I would not use `forms.ModelForm` in this scenario but I would instead use `forms.Form` instead.

Like this:-

```
from django import forms

class DriverRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(label='Phone')
    mobile = forms.IntegerField(label='Mobile')
```

In your `view function` that handles the submission of this `form` instance, you will now have 4 values coming in from your `form.cleaned_data` dictionary.

You can then handle the creation of your user object because your have a `username` and `password` in your `form.cleaned_data` dictionary.

Once you have your user object, you can now create your `Driver` object by assigning:-

```
def register_driver(request):

    form = DriverRegistrationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = DriverRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            # Creating your user object
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])

            # Creating the driver object that is related to your user object above.
            Driver.objects.create(user=user, phone=cd['phone'], mobile=cd['mobile'])

   #  .... Finish your view function
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{{ form.instance.user.username }}
```